# Snort Website Block Rule

Tags: snort

Trying to write a snort rule that prevents the system (using its IP) from accessing a specific website, tried this up to now.

```
alert tcp any any <> 'ipaddress' any (content: "web url"; msg: "Access Denied"; react:block; sid:1000005;)
```

Any ideas on why this won't work?

Answer (score 3):

Snort has several actions which can be used:

- **alert** generate an alert using the selected alert method, and then log the packet
- **log** log the packet
- **pass** ignore the packet
- **activate** alert and then turn on another dynamic rule
- **dynamic** remain idle until activated by an activate rule , then act as a log rule
- **drop** block and log the packet
- **reject** block the packet, log it, and then send a TCP reset if the protocol is TCP or an ICMP port unreachable message if the protocol is UDP.
- **sdrop** block the packet but do not log it.

These can be found on the documentation page [Snort Rule Headers](http://manual-snort-org.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/node29.html)

In your situation you want either **drop**, **reject** or **sdrop**, depending on whether you want to send a reset, and either log or not.

The reason your current one will not block is that **alert** will just log the packet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally certain, but it may be that you are using **alert** which alerts the IDS where you should be using **drop** which just drops packets going to the specified URL.